# How to retrieve element's coordinates relative to an svg viewbox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, d3.js, viewbox

In my index.html I have an svg viewbox:

```
<svg viewBox = "0 0 2000 2000" version = "1.1">
</svg>
```

I wish to animate an svg ellipse I have created such that when the ellipse is clicked it moves vertically to a certain y point we'll call TOP, and if clicked again moves back to its original position called BOTTOM. Currently I am using the following code which works to an extent.

```
var testFlag = 0;    
d3.select("#ellipseTest").on("click", function(){
if (testFlag == 0){
  d3.select(this)
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
      .transition()
        .duration(450)
        .ease("in-out")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,-650)")
    testFlag = 1;
}else{
 d3.select(this)
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,-650)")
      .transition()
        .duration(450)
        .ease("in-out")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
testFlag = 0;
}
});
```

The issue however, is that I have also made the ellipse drag-able up to the point TOP and down to the point BOTTOM. So if I drag the ellipse halfway in between TOP and BOTTOM, then click the ellipse, it animates vertically *above* TOP, instead of stopping when it reaches TOP (and like wise for BOTTOM when animating down). This seems to be a result of how the transform translate method works.
I believe I can resolve this if I create a function that dynamically returns the amount the ellipse should translate relative to where the mouse clicks (or better yet, to where the ellipse is currently position) . The problem is that I can't figure out how to get the current y position of the element relative to the viewbox, rather I can only get the position with respect to the entire page.

Here is the faulty code I am using to get the position of my click:

```
var svg2 = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
var pt = svg2.createSVGPoint();
document.documentElement.addEventListener('click',function(evt){    
    pt.x = evt.clientX;
    pt.y = evt.clientY;
    console.log('Position is.... ' + pt.y);
},false);
```

Here is my working code to make the ellipse draggable:

```
//These points are all relative to the viewbox
var lx1 = -500;
var ly1 = 1450;
var lx2 = -500;
var ly2 = 800;
function restrict(mouse){ //Y position of the mouse 
    var x;
    if ( (mouse < ly1) && (mouse > ly2) ) {
        x = mouse;
    }else if (mouse > ly1){
        x = ly1;
    }else if (mouse < ly2) {
        x = ly2;
    }
    return x;
}


var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", function(d) {
      var mx = d3.mouse(this)[0];
      var my = d3.mouse(this)[1];


      d3.select("#ellipseTest")
        .attr({
          cx: lx2,
          cy: restrict(d3.mouse(this)[1])
        });
    })
```

Comment: Why are you animating with translate and moving with x and y?

Comment: I don't understand the question? I'm very new to all this. Is there a better method?

Comment: With a transformation you need to keep track of two separate attributes when you can handle everything with one attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Animate `cy` instead of the transformation...

```
var testFlag = 0;    
d3.select("#ellipseTest").on("click", function(){
if (testFlag == 0){
  d3.select(this)
      .transition()
        .duration(450)
        .ease("in-out")
        .attr("cy", 0)
    testFlag = 1;
}else{
 d3.select(this)
      .transition()
        .duration(450)
        .ease("in-out")
        .attr("cy", 650)
testFlag = 0;
}
});
```